# Application error when pushing django project on heroku

Tags: django, python-3.x, heroku, web-deployment, django-3.0

After pushing my project to Heroku, I get an application error. Here is log tail. Couldn't understand what is an error about.

```
2020-05-25T12:55:19.445488+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user menhior1@gmail.com
2020-05-25T12:55:19.445488+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user menhior1@gmail.com
2020-05-25T12:55:19.847136+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user menhior1@gmail.com
2020-05-25T12:55:19.847136+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user menhior1@gmail.com
2020-05-25T13:05:38.136490+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/" host=zeyzak-crm1.herokuapp.com request_id=2448cb00-bc19-4bef-8438-427f79461d08 fwd="188.253.224.201" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-25T13:05:38.744109+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=zeyzak-crm1.herokuapp.com request_id=05d800b7-6a7a-4c53-8d71-1c9549af2030 fwd="188.253.224.201" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-25T16:11:40.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user menhior1@gmail.com
2020-05-25T16:12:18.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build output: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/ceb2701d-e110-4d9e-84b7-57167e335f93/activity/builds/b0593212-6cc0-46ff-a114-c52008789e8b
2020-05-25T17:47:14.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user menhior1@gmail.com
2020-05-25T17:48:07.506138+00:00 app[api]: Attach DATABASE (@ref:postgresql-silhouetted-57617) by user menhior1@gmail.com
2020-05-25T17:48:07.506138+00:00 app[api]: Running release v3 commands by user menhior1@gmail.com
2020-05-25T17:48:07.519990+00:00 app[api]: @ref:postgresql-silhouetted-57617 completed provisioning, setting DATABASE_URL. by user menhior1@gmail.com
2020-05-25T17:48:07.519990+00:00 app[api]: Release v4 created by user menhior1@gmail.com
2020-05-25T17:48:08.140682+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 93818386 by user menhior1@gmail.com
2020-05-25T17:48:08.140682+00:00 app[api]: Release v5 created by user menhior1@gmail.com
2020-05-25T17:48:19.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-05-25T17:49:04.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user menhior1@gmail.com
2020-05-25T17:49:46.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build output: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/ceb2701d-e110-4d9e-84b7-57167e335f93/activity/builds/a191374a-616a-44f3-99fe-62edd9c1f4ca
2020-05-25T20:45:20.752157+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=zeyzak-crm1.herokuapp.com request_id=305386ff-afb0-4d73-bc24-2f92b1c5a816 fwd="194.135.170.230" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-25T20:45:32.019483+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=zeyzak-crm1.herokuapp.com request_id=ad49a280-c233-432b-8252-74f0a75ee45e fwd="194.135.170.230" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-25T20:52:49.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user menhior1@gmail.com
2020-05-25T20:53:20.459407+00:00 app[api]: Deploy f46f62e9 by user menhior1@gmail.com
2020-05-25T20:53:20.459407+00:00 app[api]: Release v6 created by user menhior1@gmail.com
2020-05-25T20:53:32.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-05-25T20:54:19.652413+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=zeyzak-crm1.herokuapp.com request_id=d575c336-bece-4388-a55f-2ffe3b9aecf2 fwd="194.135.170.230" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-25T20:54:21.201709+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=zeyzak-crm1.herokuapp.com request_id=a66f1b7e-9429-4685-8537-53f13870dd11 fwd="194.135.170.230" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

This is the structure of my project(crm1 is main app, accounts secondary. Both contain standard thing inside.):

```
--crm1 --crm1
       --accounts
       --static --images
                --css
       --manage.py
       --procfile
       --requirements.txt
       --runtime
```

What is inside my procfile :

```
web: gunicorn crm1.wsgi --log-file -
```

Any ideas are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As you see error says no web process running, means gunicorn not started

First check if gunicorn added to your requirements file 
Secondary name of Procfile start by cap-letter 
For me works fine

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have miscased Procfile as procfile which was causing an issue. Fixed now.

Comment: Good to hear you can upvote the answer.